# Package to install for cuzick test

Tags: r, install.packages

Which package should I install for cuzick test? I have tried PMCMRplus, and install_github("raredd/rawr") but I am still not able to find any package for cuzick test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cuzick = function(x,z,test.type=c("two.sided", "upper", "lower")) {
    test.type <- match.arg(test.type)
    N = length(z)
    n = unique(z)

    ranks=rank(x)

    T = sum(ranks*z)

    p = (table(z)/N)
    E_Z = sum(unique(z)*p)
    E_T = 0.5*N*(N+1)*E_Z

    Var_Z = sum(unique(z)^2*p) - E_Z^2
    Var_T = N^2*(N+1)/12*Var_Z

    Zscore = (T-E_T)/sqrt(Var_T)

    if(test.type == "two.sided") {
        pval = 2*pnorm(-abs(Zscore))
    } else if(test.type == "upper") {
        pval = pnorm(Zscore,lower.tail=F)
    } else  pval = pnorm(Zscore,lower.tail=T)

    out = data.frame(Zscore,pval,test.type)
    colnames(out) = c("Z","p","testType")
    return(out)
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code. Code only answers are not considered fully helpful!